# Add up al numbers in a string C#

Tags: c#, string, loops, numbers, int

I want to add up all numbers in a string, 
I am sure this can be done easy with a `for loop`.

I have:

```
int numbers = 1234512345;

for (int i = 0 ; i numbers.Length ; i++)        
{            
    int total;            
    total = int [i];
}
```

But it won't work for a reason, I am puzzled a lot.

Comment: And where is the string? The error message the compiler gives you should give you a clue about what is wrong here. I suggest you remove all the code, and then add one piece at a time back and figure out why it doesn't compile because there's so much wrong here that you need to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, the "string" you're trying to iterate over is an int. You probably meant something along the lines of

```
string numbers = "1234512345"
```

After that, there are several ways to do this, my favorite personally is iterating over each character of the string, using a TryParse on it (this eliminates any issues if the string happens to be alphanumeric) and totaling the result. See below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string numbers = "1234512345";
        int total = 0;
        int num; // out result

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
            int.TryParse(numbers[i].ToString(), out num);
            total += num; // will equal 30
        }
        Console.WriteLine(total);

        total = 0;
        string alphanumeric = "1@23451!23cf47c";
        for (int i = 0; i < alphanumeric.Length; i++) {
            int.TryParse(alphanumeric[i].ToString(), out num);
            total += num; // will equal 32, non-numeric characters are ignored
        }
        Console.WriteLine(total);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Like others have posted though, there are several ways to go about this, it's about personal preference most of all.

Answer (score -2):

this should do what you want

```
int total = 0;
foreach(char numchar in numbers)
{
     total += (int)char.GetNumericValue(numchar);
}
```

EDIT:

1 line solution:

```
 int total = numbers.Sum(x=> (int)char.GetNumericValue(x));
```

PS: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I must have missed the part in the documentation where you can iterate the *characters* of an integer.

Comment: just add char.GetNumericValue and it works. I tested it... I just wrote the code quickly without thinking that the to int cast would take the ASCII value

Comment: added 1 line solution

Comment: The downvotes were because your original solution didn't work given that his "string" that he was trying to add was actually an int and you're iterating over the "characters" of an int. Also, your new solution doesn't completely work. What happens when you have a string with both letters and numbers?

Comment: That should probably be included in the answer then, rather than assuming the OP will be corrected by someone else.